# Matlab to MongoDB with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, matlab, driver

So I am trying to connect MatLab to MongoDB, but have encountered a problem. Here is the code I have:

```
javaaddpath('/Users/seb/Documents/MATLAB/mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar')
import com.mongodb.*;
mongoClient = MongoClient();
```

And here is my problem:

```
Undefined function or variable 'MongoClient'.

Error in TestMongo (line 11)
mongoClient = MongoClient();
```

I have searched and others seem to have this problem but nowhere have i found a definitive answer!

I am on OS X. Running latest Matlab, MongoDB 3.4.6 (installed with Brew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Download this:

```
mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar
```

and NOT

```
mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar
```

Simple fix :)